# Unable to flash my Mozilla Flame with new Firefox OS

Tags: ubuntu, adb, firefox-os

I have been following the instructions mentioned in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Developer_phone_guide/Flame for getting the task done.

The following things have been done and are working:

1. **Remote debugging** enabled and **Screen lock** disabled.
2. The `adb-tools` and `fastboot` installed. Tried both the Ubuntu as well as the Android official way.
3. The `adb devices` is displaying my device.
4. The **.zip** file has been download and extracted.
5. Running the `./flash.sh` script reboots my device then it just remains stuck at **ThunderSoft** logo.

Reading the `./flash.sh` file, it seems the last two line are to one which remain displayed on my terminal.

```
adb kill-server
adb devices
adb reboot bootloader
fastboot devices

echo "Partition table..."
fastboot flash partition gpt_both0.bin
```

Please help!

Comment: Try a `fastboot erase cache`. Also if you're in fastboot mode, try if you can only flash the commands under 'Flash apps' in flash.sh and see if that does succeed.

Comment: I can't get any listing when I run `fastboot devices`. When will that display? `adb devices` also shows

Comment: You have to get the phone into fastboot mode. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Developer_phone_guide/Flame 'Fastboot mode' header.

Comment: Same when I attempt the steps mentioned here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Developer_phone_guide/Flame#Fastboot_mode. The device keeps rebooting (after displaying the logo) or hangs with "ThunderSoft"

Comment: As said earlier, the only thing I can do is enter in System recovery with options including *apply update from ADB* and *apply update from sdcard*

Comment: If you can go into ADB you can also get into fastboot. See also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.dev.b2g/s1mHS_haWtE

Comment: Tried all these options. Problem I face is that when these instructions are followed (whether Power+VolDown or `adb reboot bootloader`) my mobile boots displaying the ThunderSoft logo and stays that way for indefinite time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was finally able to flash the device. An important point was *Some versions of the flame bootlaoder just show the thundersoft logo when in fastboot mode* which I was missing. The steps I followed:

1. Unplug the USB Cable.
2. Power off the Phone.
3. Pull battery for 10 Seconds and then place it back.
4. Press and Hold Volume Down.
5. Press and Hold Power (while still holding the Volume Down)
6. Once you see a logo, you should be in `fastboot` mode
7. Replug USB cable in.
8. Issue `sudo fastboot devices` command to verify.

This help was actually provided by *Dave Hylands* and the remaining is what is mentioned in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Developer_phone_guide/Flame

All `fastboot` were run using `sudo` command.

Answer (score 1):

You probably used the wrong image when flashing your phone. you might have
flashed the flame gaia/gecko instead of flame-kk.

see https://www.mail-archive.com/dev-b2g@lists.mozilla.org/msg11484.html

Comment: I flashed it using the official 180 packages available.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
fastboot kill-server
sudo fastboot start-server
fastboot devices
```

It'll show your device.

Comment: Whenever I run a command related to `fastboot` I get `< waiting for device >` as output and nothing happens further.