# Can't flash Firefox OS on Flame

Tags: firefox-os

My Flame phone currently runs Firefox OS 1.3 and I am trying to flash to version 2.0. After connecting the device to my computer I run 'adb devices' in the terminal and it successfully recognizes my phone. But when I try to run the script with './flash.sh' my phone reboots as it should but then gets stuck on the splash screen that reads "ThunderSoft" and the terminal simply sits there with the following message:

```
Flash nCPU...
< waiting for device >
```

I'm doing this on Ubuntu 14.04. I have remote debugging enabled as instructed. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have the udev rule define as specified here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Developer_phone_guide/Flame ?  Also you may try control-c to stop the script and run the command fastboot devices to see if the phone is in fastboot mode.  Make sure fastboot is installed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to flash my Mozilla Flame with new FirefoxOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26333398/unable-to-flash-my-mozilla-flame-with-new-firefoxos)

Comment: Yes! Needed to go into fastboot mode. Success, thanks!